# How to make a query with nested structure?

Tags: mysql, nested

I have the following table structure:
table forum

```
forum_id | parent_id
```

where parent_id - any nesting depth
table thread

```
thread_id | forum_id
```

where forum_id -foreign key table forum
table message

```
message_id | thread_id
```

where thread_id-foreign key table thread
How can I count the number of messages to a particular forum? (сonsidering that there may be nested forums) sorry for my english, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment MySQL doesn't seem to be supporting recursive SQL queries. Although, you might consider changing your data structure to achieve the goal easier.

Take a look, for example, at this question: [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462)

Comment: Please tell me then what else could be a structure of such an application?